# Right way to use DB migrations with Postgres SQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

When I use migrations (ROR, Yii or other framework) with MySQL, I often do something like this:

Migration #1

```
$this->addColumn('user_table', 'updated_at', ' AFTER status');
```

Migration #2

```
$this->addColumn('user_table', 'social_link', ' AFTER profile_id');
```

And I get "right" arranged table cols. It's looks well.

But I start use Postgres, and there no way to rearrange columns order. As a result I get table where columns goes shuffled while dev process.

It's normal situation when columns in a table is arranged with no sense?

Comment: and this migration is... what? `addColumn` is not a standard mysqli/pdo function. you mean you're doing an `alter table`?

Comment: no, I mean framework migrations - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html